# Smack + openfire - Is it possible to check the current user is administrator or not? / How to check current user details?

Tags: java, android, admin, openfire, smack

Is it possible to check if the current user is administrator or not / How to check current user details?(Java smack + openfire in Android)? 
When I try to create user on openfire admin web page. There is a option: 
Is Administrator?   (Grants admin access to Openfire)
It is possible to know if the current user has admin access to Openfire? (I mean in smack, how to check the current user is administrator of OpenFire)

Comment: Do you mean has root privileges?

Comment: I want to know if the current has admin access/privileges to Openfire. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
 account = Connection.getAccountManager();
 Collection<String> attrs = account.getAccountAttributes();
 //inspect the values in attrs, should contain the type of account
```

---

Ok.. on the user creation page.

Is Administrator? --> means that if u want to grant admin priviledges to the user that you are creating. A admin user will have all the rights to create/delete user, session, groups etc.
You may not want to provide admin previledges to all the users.

If You want to know if the *current user* or any other user that exists has admin priviledges, then goto

User/Groups-->Users-->User Summary     (here you will get all the users in the system)

The current logged in user will be denoted by a *star* next to it. (i think)
Click on the user, then it will give a summary of the user.
The *Is Administrator?:* property will be *yes* or *no* accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. I have edited my question. By the way, you have provided something useful, thanks

Comment: Thanks frewper, but it possible to check it in Android client? Actually, I want to know if the current logged in user (Android client) has admin priviledges or not. 'Collection<String> attrs = account.getAccountAttributes();' does't indicate if the user is admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the methods in AdminManager will give you some ideas.
For example,

```
public boolean isUserAdmin(org.xmpp.packet.JID jid,
                           boolean allowAdminIfEmpty)
```

and

```
public List<org.xmpp.packet.JID> getAdminAccounts()
```

You can refer to the [javadoc](http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/admin/AdminManager.html) about the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of using AdminManager to get all one server's admins:

```
/**
 * Returns a collection with the JIDs of the server's admins. The collection may include
 * JIDs of local users and users of remote servers.
 *
 * @return a collection with the JIDs of the server's admins.
 */
public Collection<JID> getAdmins() {
    return AdminManager.getInstance().getAdminAccounts();
}
```

More detail can be found in [XMPPServer.java](https://searchcode.com/file/133624981/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/XMPPServer.java).